# How to fix the error message "the system cannot find the path specified"?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I am trying to run a file in the Outputs_2019 but the command prompt is not recognizing the folder. When I tried to open the folder in the command prompt I get the error message:"the system cannot find the path specified"

I ran the folder path"file:///C:/Users/jfoum/Documents/Outputs/Ouputs_2019" in the google chrome browser and it works.

My end result would be to open a file in that Outputs_2019 folder. I took a screenshot of the issue. Thanks for the help! [Please see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJz4q.png)

Comment: There is a typo `Ouputs_2019` vs. `Outputs_2019`. Try `cd Ouputs_2019`.

Comment: I fixed the typo and could open the folder. Thank you!